# Export only column names from postgres table into CSV

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

I am new to PostgreSQL, but so far have only come across tutorials on how to export entire tables with headers to .csv.  I would like to only export field names.

How would one write a query to only export the column names of table `x` into a .csv ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 COPY (select * from table_name where false)  -- To return result without rows
 TO 'D:\File.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

or

```
create temp table tmp (like table_name); -- To copy structure into a new temp table
COPY tmp  TO 'D:/File.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
drop table tmp;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should know that from the `psql` console you can ask some useful information about table structure with `\d`command.

Of course, I understood that what you need is to retrieve that information with a SQL query executed from your application.

But, if you call `psql` with `-E` (or `--echo-hidden`), then, after typing `\d some table` (or whatever other console command) it will also output the query (or queries) used to obtain that information. Which is very useful in cases like that.

For example:

```
test=> \d foo
********* QUERY **********
SELECT c.oid,
  n.nspname,
  c.relname
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE c.relname ~ '^(foo)$'
  AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
ORDER BY 2, 3;
**************************

********* QUERY **********
SELECT c.relchecks, c.relkind, c.relhasindex, c.relhasrules, c.relhastriggers, c.relhasoids, '', c.reltablespace, CASE WHEN c.reloftype = 0 THEN '' ELSE c.reloftype::pg_catalog.regtype::pg_catalog.text END, c.relp
ersistence, c.relreplident
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
 LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class tc ON (c.reltoastrelid = tc.oid)
WHERE c.oid = '41967';
**************************

********* QUERY **********
SELECT a.attname,
  pg_catalog.format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
  (SELECT substring(pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid) for 128)
   FROM pg_catalog.pg_attrdef d
   WHERE d.adrelid = a.attrelid AND d.adnum = a.attnum AND a.atthasdef),
  a.attnotnull, a.attnum,
  (SELECT c.collname FROM pg_catalog.pg_collation c, pg_catalog.pg_type t
   WHERE c.oid = a.attcollation AND t.oid = a.atttypid AND a.attcollation <> t.typcollation) AS attcollation,
  NULL AS indexdef,
  NULL AS attfdwoptions
FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
WHERE a.attrelid = '41967' AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
ORDER BY a.attnum;
**************************

[...more...]
```

Now, combining the third query with the first one is easy to build just what you want:

```
SELECT a.attname
FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
WHERE a.attrelid = (
    SELECT c.oid
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
    WHERE c.relname ~ '^(foo)$'
)
AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
ORDER BY a.attnum;
```

> In fact, you can also change `WHERE c.relname ~ '^(foo)$'` with `WHERE c.relname = 'foo'` too. Except if you want to be able to match table names by regular expression. Which I think is not your case.

Comment: Thanks for that info!

Answer (score 1):

another method, using psql from the command line, so that superuser privileges are not required

```
psql -U user -d database -c "COPY (SELECT * FROM table WHERE FALSE) To STDOUT With CSV HEADER DELIMITER ',';" > tmp/foo.csv
```

This returns column names only, in a comma-separated list:

```
$ more tmp/foo.csv
id,name,date,status...
```